# troubles with primefaces linechart

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have two problems with primefaces `<linechart>` tag.

This is my backbean code :

```
public class LiveChartBean {
    private Integer primaryKey;


    public Integer getPrimaryKey() {
        return primaryKey;
    }


    public void setPrimaryKey(Integer primaryKey) {
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    }


    public List<ChartData> getChartData() {
        return MonitoringManager.getChartData(3);
    }

}
```

And this is my JSF page code :

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" prefix="p"%>

<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <base href="<%=basePath%>">

    <title>My JSF 'LiveChart.jsp' starting page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <f:view>
        <p:resources/>
            <h:form>
                <t:inputHidden id="primaryKey" value="#{ChartBean.primaryKey}" forceId="true" />
                <p:lineChart  live="true" value="#{ChartBean.chartData}" var="data"
                    xfield="#{data.index}">
                    <p:chartSeries  label="ResponseTime" value="#{data.data}" />
                </p:lineChart>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my faces-config entry :

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>ChartBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.pardis.healthMonitor.LiveChartBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
   <property-name>primaryKey</property-name>
   <property-class>java.lang.Integer</property-class>
   <value>#{param.primaryKey}</value>
  </managed-property>
 </managed-bean>
```

I have passed primaryKey by url to jsf page it works fine and the setPrimaryKey method

called for the first time but after that I have two problems :

1. It throws :

   ```
    javax.el.ELException: Can't set property 'primaryKey'
   ```

   on class `com.pardis.healthMonitor.LiveChartBean` to value `null`.
2. `getChartData()` method only called seven times!!!!

Comment: When do you have problem 1?
How many times do you expect getChartData() to be called?

Comment: i have problem 1 when the chart tries to refresh.


i expect that getChartData() being called until the containing window been closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, but I think these problems are primefaces bugs!

The first problem can be solved by using the `<t:savestate>` tag.

I have solved the  second problem with:

```
<p:lineChart id="Chart" value="#{ChartBean.chartData}" var="data" xfield="#{data.index}">
    <p:chartSeries  label="ResponseTime" value="#{data.data}" />
</p:lineChart>
<p:poll interval="5" actionListener="#{ChartBean.refresh}" update="Chart" />
```

By setting the `live` property to false and then refreshing the chart with the `<poll>` tag, it works fine.

Comment: i don't want to help google code because it banned my country for political issues!

Answer (score 0):

I think that question number 1 is because your bean is in request scope.

If you are using JSF2, you can write view instead of request in

`<managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>`

If you are using JSF1.2 and RichFaces, you can use

```
<a4j:keepAlive name="ChartBean" />
```

read more about [a4j:keepAlive here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_keepAlive.html)

If you use neither of above, consider using session scope and maybe removing the bean from the scope after using it with:

```
session.removeAttribute("ChartBean");
```